# java, numbers in an Array, even comes first

Tags: java

Write a java program to rearrange all the numbers in an array, even comes before odd, only use O(1) space, and should keep relative order of even and odd numbers, for example:
input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output: [2, 4, 1, 3, 5]

Comment: whats your problem, you want StackOverflow to give the code

Comment: for example you are given an array of integers, write a program to put all even numbers to the front of the array and odd to end end, but keep the relative sequence of even numbers and odd numbers, you should do it in o(1) space complicity, which means you are not allowed to use extra array of list.

Comment: Did you try this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    int temp=0;
    int a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]%2==0){

            for (int j=i;j>a;j--){
                temp=arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

Pass over the array looking at adajacent pairs of numbers.  Each time you find a pair  where the first number is odd and the second is even, swap them.  Keep a count of the number of swaps.  Keep making passes over the array until you finally make a pass where  you don't have to swap any numbers.